# Can I use 'improving' instead of 'improved'?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, verb-forms, gerunds

> So far, they have provided invaluable data on how human bodies react in crashes and have contributed greatly to **improved** vehicle design.

In this sentence, if I use 'improving' (as a gerund) instead of 'improved', is it correct?

> So far, they have provided invaluable data on how human bodies react in crashes and have contributed greatly to **improving** vehicle design.

Is this possible? (of course the meaning of sentence would be changed a little, but is it correct in grammar?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, both sentences are correct, and the meaning is slightly different in each.

> So far, they... have contributed greatly to **improved** vehicle design

Here, they have contributed to *a [new] vehicle design that has been improved*. The object of ***to*** is ***vehicle design***, and it is modified by ***improved*** ("what kind of vehicle design? an improved vehicle design"). Here, *improved* is a [*past participle*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm) acting as an adjective to modify *vehicle design*.

> So far, they... have contributed greatly to **improving** vehicle design

Here, they have contributed to *the goal/act of making improvements on [the study/science of] vehicle design*. The object of ***to*** is ***improving***, i.e., the action or goal of making improvements. In particular, it is the act of making improvements to ***vehicle design***. Here, *improving vehicle design* is a [*gerund phrase*](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm), where *improving* is the gerund noun and *vehicle design* is its object.

It's also possible to read this as *they have contributed to the study/science of vehicle design, which is currently improving*. A similar use might be "*We invested in the growing company*": we invested in the company, which was growing.

Answer (score 3):

I see absolutely no reason why you can't do this. However, perhaps you shouldn't depending on what you are writing for.

Firstly, two Google searches give us a much higher return of results for "[improved](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22improved+vehicle+design%22)" than "[improving](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Improving+vehicle+design%22)".

Why? Well, I'd hasten to say it's pretty simple. As language objects, the "-ed" past participle screams completion whilst its cousin the "-ing" participle resonates with "in progress". You will likely find that the vast majority of cases similar to the one you provide will prefer "-ed" over "-ing" because it provides that sense of completion; i.e. "The vehicles design has **already been improved**". Think of advertising, research or a variety of other fields. Giving the impression that the results of your test/products have already been implemented gives the consumer/reader a greater sense of satisfaction thanif you imply you are still working on things.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use improving instead of improved in the same sense. Both these words are adjectives with a difference in mesning as mentioned below:

1- improved means made better in quality or condition than before such as improved
   econoomy, improved vehicle design.

2- improving means getting better such as improving weather.

Comment: In some way I agree with you. but as mentioned in above my question, I wonder if I could use 'improving' as gerund not adjective(present participle). is it impossible?

Comment: I am sorry this part of your question escaped me. You are right when you use it as a gerund. ....contributed greatly to improving vehicle design is a beautiful example of the use of the gerund.